# Fixing an error where the code goes unresponsive after one cycle

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to have the for loop run 5 iterations of the code below it but once it runs once and i try to click the rectangle the code goes unresponsive.
I can't see why this is happening so i'm looking for some help.

```
def Reaction_game():
intro = True
while intro == True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #Stops game when close is selected
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            file=open('currentuser.txt', 'w') 
            file.close()
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        Reaction_times=[]
        for x in range (5):
            clicked = False
            BackGround = Background("background1.png",[0,0])
            screen.fill(white)
            screen.blit(BackGround.image, BackGround.rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, black,(0,0,1000,55))
            Font = pygame.font.SysFont('TitilliumWeb.ttf',72)
            Label = Font.render("Get Ready:", 1, white)
            screen.blit(Label, (380,0,325,75))
            pygame.display.update()
            time.sleep(2)
            screen.blit(BackGround.image, BackGround.rect)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, black,(0,0,1000,55))
            Font = pygame.font.SysFont('TitilliumWeb.ttf',72)
            Label = Font.render("Go:", 1, white)
            screen.blit(Label, (450,0,325,75))
            pygame.display.update()

            RectX = randrange(50,950)
            RectY = randrange(60,513)
            round_rect(screen,(RectX,RectY,75,40),(black),10,5,(white))
            pygame.display.update()
            TimeStart = time.time()

            while clicked !=True:
                mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                if RectX+75 > mouse[0] > RectX and RectY+40 > mouse[1] > RectY:
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                        TimeEnd = time.time()
                        ReactionTime = TimeEnd - TimeStart
                        Reaction_times.append(ReactionTime)
                        clicked = True
                else:
                    pass
Reaction_game()
```

I expect the code to run 5 iterations of this little reaction time game but it doesn't even get past the first loop before going unresponsive.

Comment: you should use `for event ...` inside your loop. Without  `for event ...` it can't get new mouse position. Even `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` needs `for event ...` to work correctly. Because `pygame.event.get()` gets events from system and create data used by `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

Comment: inside `while click` you use `event.type` , `event.button` but they have always the same value because you don't get new value using `for event ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `for event in pygame.event.get():` inside `while clicked` to get new events from system. Without this you have the same values in `event.type` and `even.button`.

Even `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` can't work correclty because it uses data created by `pygame.event.get()` (or similar)

If you have event `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`, `MOUSEBUTTONUP` then you have mouse position in `event.pos` and you don't need `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`

```
while not clicked:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if RectX+75 > event.pos[0] > RectX and RectY+40 > event.pos[1] > RectY:
                TimeEnd = time.time()
                ReactionTime = TimeEnd - TimeStart
                Reaction_times.append(ReactionTime)
                clicked = True
```

---

**EDIT:**

You can keep Rectangle position and size in `pygame.Rect()`

```
   RectX = randrange(50,950)
   RectY = randrange(60,513)

   rect = pygame.Rect(RectX, RectY, 75, 40)
```

and then you can use `rect` instead of `(RectX,RectY,75,40)`

```
   round_rect(screen, rect, black , 10, 5, white)
```

and you can use `rect` to check if you clicked in rectangle `rect.collidepoint(event.pos)`

```
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
       if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
           TimeEnd = time.time()
           ReactionTime = TimeEnd - TimeStart
           Reaction_times.append(ReactionTime)
           clicked = True
```

---

**EDIT:** working example with other changes - ie. I use `pygame.time.wait()` instead of `time.sleep()` and `pygame.time.get_ticks()` instead of `time.time()`. Both use miliseconds instead of seconds.

```
import pygame
import random

# --- constants ---

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 600))

reaction_times= []

for x in range(5):
    clicked = False

    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, 1000, 55))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 72)
    label = font.render("Get Ready:", 1, WHITE)
    screen.blit(label, (380, 0, 325, 75))
    pygame.display.update()

    pygame.time.wait(2000) # 2000ms = 2s

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, (0, 0, 1000, 55))
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 72)
    label = font.render("Go:", 1, WHITE)
    screen.blit(label, (450, 0, 325, 75))
    pygame.display.update()

    x = random.randrange(50, 950)
    y = random.randrange(60, 513)
    rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 75, 40)

    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACK, rect)
    pygame.display.update()

    time_start = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    while not clicked:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
                if rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    print('clicked')
                    time_end = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                    reaction_time = (time_end - time_start)/1000 # convert to seconds
                    reaction_times.append(reaction_time)
                    clicked = True

print(reaction_times)
pygame.quit()
```